# Inserting 3 Excel columns into 1 label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have three columns of data.  Is there a way using vba to insert the information into a label on a userForm?

Here is the updated code I have:

```
Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = 373

For rowNum = 2 To lastRow

report = Sheets("DATA2").Range("F" & rowNum).Text & _
"      " & Sheets("DATA2").Range("G" & rowNum).Text & _
"      " & Sheets("DATA2").Range("H" & rowNum).Text & vbCrLf

Next rowNum

End Sub
```

Comment: You can hardcode lastRow as 373 if it will never change (i.e. a Constant) or you can use some other code to define which row is the last one in the column. For example, if you wanted to find the last used row in column F, use:    `lastRow = Sheets("DATA2").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: @Widor:  I tried that and it still only inserts the first row.

Comment: @Mike: with my code or your code? You're using `.Range("F2").Text` when it should be `.Range("F" & rowNum).Text`

Comment: @Widor:  I changed the above code and now it doesn't insert anything.  Sorry, am I still doing something wrong?  I'm new to vba and I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: Well, you haven't defined what `report` is, nor assigned it to the `.Text` of your Label yet? If you've done that but not updated your question, check it's setting `report` with a `MsgBox(report)` to pop up a message with the value.

Comment: @Widor: report is the name of the label.

Comment: Then it needs to be `report.Caption = ...` because you have to set the Caption property of the Label to be the string you generated in the loop.

Comment: @Widor:  I changed it to say report.Caption and still nothing.  I noticed you said the property of the label.  Do I need to change something in the userForm for the label?  Or is this done by report.Caption?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's over writing it on each loop. Try `report.Caption = report.Caption & ` instead. All `Label` controls have a property called `Caption`, which you'll see in the Properties window when you're designing your form. In the code, you need to access this as `report.Caption` because `report` is the ID of your Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim rowNum as Integer 'loop counter  
Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = 'some code to set the row number of the bottom row

For rowNum = 1 to lastRow
    With ActiveWorksheet
        myLabel.Text = myLabel.Text & .Range("A" & rowNum).Text & " " & .Range("B" & rowNum).Text & " " & .Range("C" & rowNum).Text & vbCrLf
    End With
Next rowNum
```

**EDIT**

Updated to append each loop instead of over-writing

Comment: That works for the first line, but the rest of the columns doesn't show up.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, didn't read the question properly. have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the original post above to reflect the code I have from what you posted.  I don't know exactly what code to put in where it says "lastRow ="  My last row is 373.  Besides that is everything else correct?  Thanks

Comment: @Mike: See my reply to your original question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your label can handle multiple lines, you could write a loop that iterates through each column of data and appends it to a String as a new line, and then set the text field of that label to the string you created.